# How to disable responsive view on wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

My website is http://nzexport.net/. 
I'm trying to disable the mobile view which is the responsive view of the wordpress theme. To make the mobile view is the same as the PC one. And i tried some ways like removing the view tag, fixed width css, disable responsive option in VisualComposer. But none of them word properly. Can anyone tell me how could i disable the responsive thing?
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

Remove all the media queries you have in style.css and delete the responsive.css file from FTP(if you are using it). 
and remove the meta tag.